# Proper order syntax for MySQL INNER JOIN ON (Basic Q)

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following MySQL query statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE 1
```

Does it matter if my inner join on statement is `table1.id = table2.id` vs. `table2.id = table1.id`?

Comment: Thanks @ypercube. I didn't think so, but just wanted to know if there was something I might be missing that someday down the road would cause my query to not perform as I am presently designing it.

Comment: and... thanks for the drive by down vote. I love it when you get penalized for wanting to learn. Thought that was one of the things S.O. was for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional or performance difference between the two options you presented.

It's purely a stylistic choice.

Personally I prefer this style, but I'm sure there are others who do it differently:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table1.id 
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks @IkeWalker. Appreciate the confirmation that there is no syntactical difference. And I agree with you - I prefer to order the `ON` statement the way you show above as (for me) it is easier to read and seems more logical in its flow.